# every first react-native component gets typescript error

Tags: typescript, react-native

When I use the Text component of react-native, I get this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: TextProps | Readonly<TextProps>): Text', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Text> & Readonly<TextProps>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: TextProps, context: any): Text', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Text> & Readonly<TextProps>'.ts(2769)
```

My code:

```js
// .tsx file
import {Text} from 'react-native'
...

<Text>123</Text>
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@assets/*": [
        "src/assets/*"
      ],
      "@config/*": [
        "src/config/*"
      ],
      "@src/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
      "react-native": [
        "node_modules/@mrn/react-native"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

when I move the mouse on "Text" component, I get this error, and I can not solve it, sad

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: TextProps | Readonly<TextProps>): Text', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Text> & Readonly<TextProps>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: TextProps, context: any): Text', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Text> & Readonly<TextProps>'.ts(2769)
```

The "Text" component is import from react-native and Text is an official component.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What's the name of the file? What does your tsconfig look like? Can you give a little context on the project setup?